# Eclipse where the workspace settings are registered

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)
Windows 10

The structure of my project is as follows: there is a shared folder and there are several maven projects (microservices) in it. I deleted one of the project from workspace.
Now I want to add it back (File->Open Project...),

[image]

but I get an error in response:

```
Select at least one folder to import as project.
```

As I understand it, the problem is that such a folder is already registered somewhere in the Eclipse settings, because if I change its name, it is added without errors.
Where is this information with the project name stored in Eclipse?
How can I delete it so that I can add a project without changing its name?

I tried to delete all configuration files from the project.

Created a new workspace and switched to it.

Nothing helps

Comment: What do you mean by _"File->Open Project..."_? _File > Open Projects from File System..._? If yes, which directory did you choose? And which files or folder do you exactly deleted (_"I tried to delete all configuration files from the project."_)?

Comment: I select the root folder of the project. I always do that and it works. Deleted all files except source codes. I.e. left a clean project as github

Comment: "Select at least one folder to import as project." does not imply that there's already a project by the same name, it is literally telling you that you haven't picked what to import as the project.

Comment: I don't know what you always do and I still don't know what you mean by _"File->Open Project..." Deleting all files except source code is not the recommended way. Please improve your question with the exact steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have added a menu item that I choose

Comment: It goes straight from clicking in the menu to the error message? How was this Eclipse installed? What O.S. is it on, and what are the versions of Eclipse and the O.S.?

Comment: @nitind, This happens with any project if you delete it from the workspace and then try to add it. If you choose a new project name, then there is no such error

Comment: What does the _Import Projects from File System or Archive_ dialog show?

Comment: If I do Import Projects, then it is added as a set of folders, and not as a Maven project. That's why I don't do it. And I always add as shown in the picture. But the fact is that even if you make Import Projects, and then delete it, then the same Eclipse project will not allow you to add it a second time. Therefore, there is no difference in the way the project is added.

Comment: To detect it as a Maven project, the `pom.xml` file is needed. Do you have a `pom.xml` file and is it valid?

Comment: Yes, there is a file in the project pom.xml

Comment: Have you tried the Maven-specific project import wizard? And does it go straight from clicking on the menu action to the error message?